# Creating a unique URL safe hash

Tags: c#, encryption, hash

I want to hash/encode a unique integer (database ID) to create a similarly unique string.

It needs to meet the following requirements:

1. Must start with a letter or number, and can contain only letters and numbers.
2. All letters in a container name must be lowercase.
3. Must be from 3 through 63 characters long (although the shorter the better)

The result does not need to be reversible, just repeatable - so a 1-way hash would be fine.

Comment: But is reversible fine? Reversible can be much shorter.

Comment: (And I assume with number you mean ASCII digit, and with letter you mean ASCII letter?)

Comment: The shorter (# of bits) the hash, the more chance for collisions.  A simple (and short) way would to get the output of CRC32 in hex string format, and to a `.ToLowerCase()` on it.  Also, the shorter the hash, the easier it will be to "break" it, if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be a base 36 encoding. The output will be a string between one and six characters.

```
public static string EncodeBase36(int i)
{
  Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(i>=0);
  //Base conversion
  string s="";
  while(i!=0)
  {
    int digit = i % 36;
    i/=36;
    if(digit<10)
      s=((char)('0'+digit)).ToString()+s;
    else
      s=((char)('a'+digit-10)).ToString()+s;
  }
  // Enforce minimum length
  while(s.Length<3)
  {
    s = "0" + s;
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I did originally try base36 encoding but was worried about clashes caused by padding in this way?

Comment: Not sure what you're worried about. No matter how many `0`s you pad, an integer never becomes another integer.

Comment: I'd +1 this if I wasn't out of daily votes...I use Base62 frequently (same thing, but with case-sensitivity) to generate URL-friendly values, JavaScript-friendly variables, HTML-friendly IDs, etc.

Comment: Are you not just padding the encoded result? So 1 encodes as "0jh" - is it not possible that another (larger) integer could generate the same value?

Comment: The first part of this code never produces any leading `0`s. Just this of how `i.ToString()`, the Base10 encoding would behave. No matter how many leading `0`s you have, the number stays the same.

Comment: +1. Note you may consider writing code for Base32 encoding as it would make creation of any Urls with data much easier. As mentioned earlier url-friendly charset for Base64 may be another option but generally painful for Urls as they often (technically incorrectly, but still) treated as case-insensetive.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you cannot use base 64 encoded MD5 using the [`MD5CryptoServiceProvider` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider.aspx) or SHA1 using the [`SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha1cryptoserviceprovider.aspx)? I am not aware of a cryptanalysis of base 36 but I would guess the collision rate is probably better with MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: "All letters in a container name must be lowercase"

Comment: And hashes are much longer than reversible encoding. So there is little reason to use them, unless you require a property unique to them, such as one-way-ness.

Comment: "but I would guess the collision rate is probably better with MD5 or SHA1" Base36 encoding is reversible. This implies that no collision exists. Just like `i.ToString()` AKA Base10 encoding, has no collisions.

Comment: @CodesInChaos The length of the hash is irrelevant from the size of input, you could have a 1 bit hash if you were so inclined to make one (eg. parity bit).

Comment: @Matthew Since the OP wants uniqueness, a hash must be long enough to get a low collision risk. This means it needs to be more than twice as long as the output of a reversible function.

Comment: @CodesInChaos maybe I missed the point, why not just output the actual integer instead of making it *slightly* shorter by base encoding it?

Comment: @Matthew I don't know what the OPs goal is. But even if you want to make the transformation  secret, a hash is the wrong choice here. In that case I'd use a block-cipher with small block size. An unkeyed hash is trivial to brute-force since the input space is so small.

Answer (score 1):

If you are fine with reversible (as Base36) than there is already built in Base16 (hex) formatting that probably would work too to slightly hide the number from regular people: `String.Format("{0:x}", 1235)` or `12345.ToString("x")`

Comment: IMO the hiding property of Hex or Base36 is so weak that it's not worth mentioning. The one thing that Base36 offers is that it's shorter than Base10.